# Thumbs not showing in 'insert file' in admin

Tags: admin, image, image-upload, wysiwyg, thumbnail

For backend - both in the 'Media Gallery' and 'insert file' the thumbs are not being shown.  Broken links are being shown.

1. I have tried resetting all the file and folder permissions - no change
2. I have tried enabling the WYSIWYG editor - no change
3. I have tried creating a WYSIWYG folder in the Media folder - no change

The images show on the frontend without any problems.  Using 2.3.5-p1 on Cloudways hosting.
I have added a picture and the code relating to one of the Thumbs..

`<div data-row="file" class="filecnt" id="d2FzaHJvb20uanBn" data-size="135749" data-mime-type="image/jpeg"> <p class="nm" style="height:75px;"> <img src="https://www.Samplecode.co.uk/pub/media/.thumbscatalog/category/washroom.jpg?rand=1594639661" alt="washroom.jpg"> </p> <small>1491x965 px.</small><br> <small>washroom.jpg</small> </div>`

[image: picture showing thumbs not showing]

Comment: Update: I have discovered this is due to a server rule blocking folders which start with a '.'  I have asked cloudways help to change the rule.

Answer (score 0):

Did you find a solution to this with Cloudways?
I seem to be having the same discussion with Cloudways support and they cant find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

By default, all servers on Cloudways blocks access for directories whose name starts with "`.`" except `.well-known` folder.

Exception is required for `.thumbs` and `.thumbswysiwyg` in nginx configuration file in order to show thumbs images

Just ask support to allow it in `/etc/nginx/additional_server_conf` by replacing this piece of code

> location ~ /.(?!well-known/|*).*$ {
> deny all;
> }

with

> location ~ /.(?!well-known/|thumbs/|thumbswysiwyg/).*$ {
> deny all;
> }

Restart **nginx** service and it will Work!